# Call for input inside moduleServer

Tags: shiny, shinymodules

I'm learning Shiny modules. And I'm stuck in a very silly thing: I don't know how to call an input inside `moduleServer`. In this reprex, the table does not show, I think its because the `getInput` argument is not properly used in the server. Here's a reprex:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

tablaResumen <- function(id, getInput, tabla1, tabla2) {
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    output$table <- renderDT({
      if(getInput == FALSE){
        tabla <- tabla1
        }else{
        tabla <- tabla2
        }
      DT::datatable(tabla, escape = FALSE, rownames = FALSE)
    })  
  })
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  checkboxInput("input1", label = "Change table"),
  DTOutput("table1")
  )

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  tablaResumen("table1", input$input1, mtcars, iris)
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
library(shiny)
library(DT)

tablaResumen <- function(id, parent_in, get, tabla1, tabla2) {
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    output$mytable <- renderDT({
       
      if(parent_in[[get]] == FALSE){
        tabla <- tabla1
      }else{
        tabla <- tabla2
      }
      DT::datatable(tabla, escape = FALSE, rownames = FALSE)
    })  
  })
}

tablaResumenUI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  DTOutput(ns("mytable"))
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  checkboxInput("input1", label = "Change table"),
  tablaResumenUI("table")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  tablaResumen("table", parent_in = input, "input1", mtcars, iris)
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Things are a little tricky here.

1. To render the table, you must put the `DTOutput` under the same namespace as your mod server. The way we usually do it is by creating a mod UI function and use `NS` to wrap the id to create the namespace.
2. You module is depend on a reactive input value `input$input1`, but the server function itself is not reactive. This means if you provide it as an argument for the mod function, it will be run only one time, so `getInput` will never be changed after the app is initialized. It becomes a fixed value. To get the reactive value of `input1`, you need to provide the parent input as an argument as access from there.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but this is not a good solution for me, because I need the input that is defining `getInput` to be able to be named in the `moduleServer` function (the input's name can vary in what I'm trying to achieve).

Comment: @DavidJorquera then pass the input name as the second argument

Comment: Thanks a lot! With your help I managed to get to a solution that does what I was trying to do. I would appreciate if you could edit your answer to paste the code I put as an answer (is built on top of your solution). Then I will erase it and accept your answer as the solution.

Comment: @DavidJorquera ok, great, just did.